# Can't see the calculated column "Start Date"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I created Start Date calculated column, now I can't see the column in the list setting.But when I try to create Start Date, I get a alert the column name you entered is already in use or reserved.

Anyone who could help me on this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42229/discussion-on-question-by-rishabh-shukla-cant-see-the-calculated-column-start).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SharePoint Designer.
2. Open the website that contains your list with the calculated column.
3. Click on "Lists and Libraries" in the left column (under Site Objects).
4. On the right, click on the list that contains your calculated column.
5. Under "Content Types",  click on the content type then check your calculated column name .
6. In the content type screen, click "Edit content type columns" and check if it was hidden.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I already did using designer and it's not there.

Comment: what's the type of your list ? Is it Task List ?

Comment: It's a form library